# How to use static information in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a card designed in react.  The card needs to appear throughout the project (on different pages).

Each card will have different titles, subtitles, and amount.

How can I go about doing this? I thought about creating an object and then looping through it.  Calling the card component on different pages, but this won't allow me to change the content depending on the page.

Card.js

```
const cards = [
   {title: Card A, subtitle: Card A Subtitle},
   {title: Card A2, subtitle: Card A2 Subtitle},
   {title: Card A3, subtitle: Card A3 Subtitle},
]

{cards.map through cards to display it}
```

ExamplePageA.js. (Card:3, title: CardA, Subtitle:CardASubtitle....)

```
<Card />
<OtherStuff />
```

ExamplePageB.js (Card:2, title: cardB, Subtitle: CardBSubtitle....)

```
<Card />
<OtherStuffB />
<OtherStuffToo />
```

Comment: What about passing props to your card when you use them on those different pages? This is the react standard aproach. If you are ok with this kind of solution. Please share your Card component

Comment: @DaviCheliMiquelim Is it possible to pass in multiple props (of the same kind). For example, 3 types of titles. And making it readable?

Comment: Yes it is. Take a look at my answer. You could add as many props as you want

Answer (score 0):

You must pass props to your card component so that you can use it multiple times with different data:

```
export const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.title}<div/>
    <div>{props.subtitle}<div/>
  )
}
```

And then you should use it like this:

```
<Card title="Your title" subtitle="Your subtitle"/>
```

If you want to map through your cards array you should approach it like this inside of return in your parent component:

```
{cards.map((card) => <Card title={card.title} subtitle={card.subtitle}/>)}
```